# Some Azure Devops committer/author emails have guid instead of domain

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I'm listing the contributors in an Azure Devops services git repository, and seeing some users with a guid instead of a domain in the email address, i.e `username@xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

I've tried to track this guid back to any user property, but couldn't find any match.

Any idea on where it could have come from? I'd want to be able to track it back to the user and I don't think I can use the username as a unique identifier (its domain specific).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git stores your name and email address in its [config file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config). This file can be at the system level, global to your account on your computer, or local to a repository. If a name and email aren't found in any of these places, Git will do its best to get this information from your operating system. Your details are included in the commit, marking you as the author of that commit.

> **Where does Azure DevOps Services get your name and email?**
>
> Your details in Azure DevOps Services come from your profile. Your
>   profile was originally populated from details in your Microsoft
>   Account or Azure Active Directory account, but you may change these
>   details yourself. **When you edit a file in the web or complete a PR,
>   Azure Repos supplies your profile details as the author of the
>   commit.** This is another opportunity for your name or email address
>   to be specified differently.

Please check both of Git and Azure DevOps Service and make sure the name and e-mail is correct.

--How do I change my information in Git and Azure DevOps Services?

In Git, you can run two commands to change your name and email
   address:

```
git config --global user.name "Frances Totten"
git config --global user.email "frances_t@fabrikam.com"
```

In Azure DevOps Services, you can update your profile by clicking your picture in the upper right corner and choosing [My profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-your-preferences?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).

Besides, you could also try to change the author displayed for past commits. More details please kindly refer our tutorial here-- **[How names work in Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-names?view=azure-devops)**

Comment: I need to deal with the historical data already set up with cryptic emails, less interested in future best practices

Comment: Hi Mugen, If you want to modify the history info. I don't think this is available to do this. When you commit to your local repo, Git includes your name and email address as part of the commit. This can sometimes lead to confusion. The name and email on your commits may not match the identity you log in with on a Git host like Azure Repos. Further, you may have commits under several different names and email addresses even though you were the author for each of them. You should make sure this user lately will not use the strange `username@xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` format

Comment: Hi @Mugen  just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve? If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for *marking it as an answer*which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 1):

That's a strange one. Maybe an issue with how Active directory is syncing with [Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-names?view=azure-devops#where-does-azure-devops-services-get-your-name-and-email). I would try and validate with a user who has the problem what they have in their [local git config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-names?view=azure-devops#where-does-git-get-your-name-and-email).

Something to be aware of is the email format enforcement you can do for git repositories. **Project Settings -> Repositories -> Policies**.

`https://dev.azure.com/{collection}/{project}/_settings/repositories?repoGroup=true&_a=pushpolicy`